# Add extra field to the android call logs programmatically

Tags: android, calllog

I explored about adding extra field to android calllogs. It says we cant add . But is it possible in any other way? I just wanted to add one custom made field to call logs to send some default message or something like that . Any help??

Comment: It surely is not possible to change the semantics of the DB of the CALL_LOG DB, and even if you do, there is no way you can change the data that the CALL_LOG_ROWS shows. However, may be you can append one of existing fields, that is used to create the call log with your DATA.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, what you can do is create a seperate Logger file on your application launch and keep writing the stacktrace along with your custom message in that file and save it in your SD Card. This way you can see the trace along with the custom message you wanna send.